# if null value advance to select next column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I only need one blood pressure value from the table where the columns are

`B/P | Sitting | Lying | Standing`

Unusually, there is a GENERAL blood pressure, and then a blood pressure for each posture. I basically need ONLY one of those values and the importance is left to right. If bloodpressure is null, select the sitting value, if sitting value is null, select lying value, if lying value is null, select standing value

I need something like

```
SELECT
    case when bloodpressure is null or bloodpressure = ''
        then case when sitting is null or sitting = ''
            then case when lying is null or lying = ''
                then case when standing is null or standing = ''
                    standing
                end
                lying
            end
            sitting
        end
    bloodpressure
    end
    as bloodpressure
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will looks like:

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN ISNULL(bloodpressure,'') <> '' THEN bloodpressure
        WHEN ISNULL(sitting,'') <> '' THEN sitting
        WHEN ISNULL(lying,'') <> '' THEN lying
        WHEN ISNULL(standing,'') <> '' THEN standing
    ELSE 
        '0' END AS bloodpressure
```

I add also `ELSE` condition as `0` because if all fields are empty you must receive 0. If this is not required you can remove it.

If all enpty values are `NULL` then you can use [`COALESCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN bloodpressure IS NOT NULL
               AND bloodpressure <> '' THEN bloodpressure
         WHEN sitting IS NOT NULL
               AND sitting <> '' THEN sitting
         WHEN lying IS NOT NULL
               AND lying <> '' THEN lying
         WHEN standing IS NOT NULL
               AND standing <> '' THEN standing
       END AS bloodpressure
```

`IS NOT NULL AND standing <> ''` can be replaced with `NULLIF(standing,'') IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @Lashane - Yep, Updated

Answer (score 0):

If the values are either null or valid you can try:

```
SELECT ISNULL(bloodpressure, ISNULL(sitting, ISNULL(lying, standing))) AS bloodpressure
```

or using `COALESCE` (as @Bogdan Bogdanov suggests)

```
SELECT COALESCE(bloodpressure, sitting, lying, standing) AS bloodpressure
```

Comment: It must also be not `empty string` and if all elements are only `NULL` (not `empty string`) you can use `COALESCE`.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use coalesce + nullif:

```
select coalesce (
  nullif(bloodpressure,''), 
  nullif(sitting,''), 
  nullif(lying,''), 
  standing)
```

Also, you should not store empty strings in your columns, that's just bad database design.